# Echo one row as different

Tags: php, html-select

When I'm inserted this in one colum (name is size): s, m, xl, xxl. Can I echo them as four different items? Like in a dropdown box:

```
<select>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
</select>
```

[This](http://s22.postimg.org/6ymq53znh/size.png) is what I mean with 'one colum':

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explode the string on `", "`, which will create an array. Then iterate through the array and append the options.

```
$string = "s, m, xl, xxl";
echo "<select>\n";
foreach(explode(", ",$string) as $s){
    echo "<option>".$s."</option>\n";
}
echo "</select>\n";
```

Comment: Thanks. But what if I have two rows, and the first row has values: m, s and the second has values s, m, xl, xxl?

Comment: You mean so you have multiple selects, or combine them? Just put this inside your while statement, changing `$string` to your row variable.

Answer (score 0):

u can use explode () and then use separate value as ur option value

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php